# Why drawing map from google docs takes +50seconds

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Why drawing a map from google docs takes +50seconds, I have just two columns and 40 rows:
Columns are CITY, NAME.   some cities are duplicate.   According to firebug, network connection takes just 2-3 secs.   All cities are in 1 country, can I somehow optimize this?

My code is:

```
  google.load('visualization', '1',
          {'packages': ['table', 'map']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

      function initialize() {
        // The URL here is the URL of the spreadsheet.
        // This is where the data is.
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(
            'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=xx');        
        query.send(draw);
      }

      function draw(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          alert('Error in query');
        }




        var geoView = new google.visualization.DataView(response.getDataTable());
        //geoView.setColumns([0, 1,2]);

        var table =
            new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(response.getDataTable(), {showRowNumber: false});

        var map =
            new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
        map.draw(geoView, {showTip: true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty simple and I can't see anything that would slow it down. In my application I am using several visualizations, including the table view and the map, displaying 77 rows. It takes approximately 7-15 seconds. It might just be your connection or domain.